# Запрос разных сумм на отрезке

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

У меня есть массив a1, a2, . . . , an и мне нужно обработать несколько типов запросов, всего запросов - q
 а) по числам pos и x выполнить присваивание a[pos] := x;
 б) по числам l и r вывести sum ai, где l≤i≤r то есть, al + ... + ar
 в) по числам l и r вывести sum ai * aj, где l≤i≤j≤r то есть, al * al + al * a(l + 1) + ... + ar*ar
 г) по числам l и r вывести sum ai * aj * ak, где l≤i≤j≤k≤r то есть, al* al * al + al *al * a(l + 1) + ... + ar * ar * ar

Мне нужно всё это выполнять за O(n + qlogn)

Comment: Дерево отрезков

Comment: А можно поподробнее?

Comment: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree

Comment: Нет, я понимаю, что такое дерево отрезков, мне интересно, как с помощью него решать мою задачу. В частности выполнять запросы в) и г)